# how to remove snap packages after removing snap?

Tags: snap

I removed snap by `sudo apt remove snapd`.

now how to delete an special package that was installed with snap ?

Comment: Which "an special package" are you referring to?

Comment: __clion__ and __pycharm-professional__

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

You need `snap` to remove the snap you want. As mentioned [in this article](https://techwiser.com/remove-snap-ubuntu/):

> If you find packages installed under snap list, you’d have to remove
> them by using the following command.
>
> ```
> sudo snap remove --purge package-name
> ```
>
> “package-name” needs to be removed with the actual installed package
> name.